# How translation affects vectors angle?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be vectors in finite-dimensional Euclidean space, s.t. $||\vec a|| > 0,$ $||\vec b|| > 0$.

What is the value of $cos(\beta)$ if $\beta = \angle(\vec v, \vec w)$ and  $\vec v = \vec a + [1, 1, \ldots, 1]$, $\vec w = \vec b + [1, 1, \ldots, 1]$?

Answer (score 0):

The cosine of the angle $\alpha$ between the non-zero vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ is
$$
\cos(\alpha)=\frac{{\vec v}\cdot{\vec w}}{|\vec v||\vec w|}
$$
where the dot denotes the scalar product and $|\cdot|$ the norm.

Upon translation by a vector $\vec x$ and under the assumption that $\vec v+\vec x$ and $\vec w+\vec x$ are still non-zero the angle changes so that
$$
\cos(\alpha^\prime)=\frac{({\vec v+\vec x})\cdot({\vec w+\vec x})}{|\vec v+\vec x||\vec w+\vec x|}.
$$
While one can certainly make the latter expression explicit in terms of the components of the three vectors involved, the relation between the two expression is by no means simple except maybe for a few special cases.